# Besides contests of arms, do Vulcans participate in either individual or team sports?

Tags: star-trek, vulcan

Vulcans are adept, or can be, with weapons and display physical ability and mental agility to work together in battle. A [GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAUsy.gif) I posted in chat made me wonder about their participation in individual or team sports. What sports, if any, do Vulcans take part in on their home planet?

[image: bouncy]

Comment: [Baseball](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/USS_T%27Kumbra_personnel#Logician_team_members) was played by [some Vulcans](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Logicians), although probably not a standard thing on Vulcan.

Comment: There's no translation for the word "sport" in the official (Okrand) Vulcan dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### No, they don't

In [Issue #024 of the 2015 IDW Star Trek (Ongoing) comics](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Star_Trek_Ongoing,_Issue_24), nuSpock describes sport as being illogical and **hence of no interest to Vulcans**.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I know Tuvok enjoys the odd game of [Kal-Toh](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Kal-toh).

It's a kind of sport... maybe.

[image]

Comment: More of a pastime.

Comment: @Richard maybe for you... But I play to win!!